# Choices as choice option in choice field Type in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, multiple-choice, choicefield

Maybe is a little confusing question but here is an explanation by the code:

is there a way to do something like this?

```
$builder->add(
            'doYouWantToEnterData',
            'choice',
            array(
                'choices'   => array(
                    0   => 'no',
                    1   => 'choices_name',
                ),
            ),
          'extend' =>true 
        )
        ->add(
            'choices_name',
            'choice',
            array(
                'choices'   => array(
                    0   => 'text_input_name',
                    1   => 'select_box_name',
                ),
            ),
          'extend' =>true 
        )
        ->add('text_input_name' )
        ->add(
            'select_box_name',
            'choice',
            array(
                'choices'   => array(
                    0   => 'choice_1',
                    1   => 'choice_2',
                ),
            ),
        );
```

as you can see the **choices_name** is the option in the option named **doYouWantToEnterData** and options in the **choices_name** are **text_input_name** and **select_box_name**

---

is there a way to create this kind of stuff in the FormType class ??

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no such functionality bundled in the standart form component.
The best way of doing this is to create [custom form type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) + some JS code to show/hide necessary fields.
And i suggest you to watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAX13g5orwo) (there is an example of similiar problem with choice and optional text).